# Numpy arrays with rows meeting 3 conditions involving the matching of elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This question has three related parts. Consider the numpy array sample, P, having 4 columns.

```
import numpy as np

P = np.array([-4, 5, 2, -3],
             [-5, 6, 0, -5],
             [-6, 5, -2, 5],
             [1, -2, 1, -2],
             [2, -4, -6, 8],
             [-4, 9, -4, 2],
             [0, -8, -8, 1]])
```

I'm hoping to learn how to build three new arrays:

a) P1:  This is P where the **first** element of a row has a match in the **last 3** elements.

b) P2:  This is P where the **first 2** elements of a row have a match in the **last 2** elements.

c) P3:  This is P where the **first 3** elements of a row have a match in the **last** element.

The outcomes, for the small sample array, would be:

```
P1 = [[-5, 6, 0, -5],
      [1, -2, 1, -2],
      [-4, 9, -4, 2]]


P2 = [[-5, 6, 0, -5],
      [-6, 5, -2, 5],
      [1, -2, 1, -2],
      [-4, 9, -4, 2],
      [0, -8, -8, 1]]

P3 =  [-5, 6, 0, -5],
      [-6, 5, -2, 5],
      [1, -2, 1, -2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P1` and `P3` are constructed the same way:

```
P1mask = (P[:, 0:1] == P[:, 1:]).any(axis=1)
P3mask = (P[:, -1:] == P[:, :-1]).any(axis=1)

P1 = P[P1mask, :]
P3 = P[P3mask, :]
```

The only really interesting thing here is that I'm indexing the columns as slices `0:1` and `-1:` instead of just `0` and `-1` to preserve shape and enable broadcasting.

`P2` can be constructed in a similar manner, although the solution is not very general:

```
P2mask = (P[:, 0:1] == P[:, 2:]).any(axis=1) | (P[:, 1:2] == P[:, 2:]).any(axis=1)
P2 = P[P2mask, :]
```

A more general solution would be to broadcast the two segments together with a new dimension so that the comparison done with `|` manually above can be automated:

```
split = 2
P2mask = (P[:, :split, None] == P[:, None, split:]).any(axis=(1, 2))
P2 = P[P2mask, :]
```

`P1` and `P3` are just the cases for `split = 1` and `split = 3`, respectively.

Comment: Your indexing of columns as slices is a technique I can use in other places as well.  I really found the general solution insightful.

Comment: An extra P crept into the definition of P3Mask in the first cell.

Answer (score 1):

You want to select all rows that fulfill a given condition, so you need to iterate over the rows of `P`, build a `boolean array` and apply it to the rows of `P`. In your case, the easiest way I can think of to check if there are shared elements, is to create two `set`s and check if their intersection is empty or not. This can be done via `set.isdisjoint`.

Final code:

```
P1 = P[[not set(row[:1]).isdisjoint(row[1:]) for row in P], :]
```

Analogous for P2 and P3.

Comment: You do not want to build a set for each row individually unless your dataset is much wider than it is tall.

Comment: Keep in mind that building a set is `O(n)`, which is what a one-time linear lookup is

Comment: Works fine for P1 and P2, but P3 != P1.

Comment: Right, my bad. Also works for P3 though. Might not be most efficient, but has the same principle code for all 3.